# clone したパッケージの autoload だけを読み込むには？

Tags: elisp

package.el で、 MELPA に登録されているようなパッケージ(具体的には、 [docker.el](https://github.com/Silex/docker.el))を、手元にクローンしてから利用しようと考えています。理由は、適宜修正を入れながら (そして、PR を送ったりしながら) パッケージを利用したいからです。

手元にレポジトリを落としてきて、そのパスを load-path に加えた状態なのですが、
このままだと、 `require` しないと、該当機能を利用することができません。
できれば、 autoload で必要に応じて、 load するようにしたいです。

このパッケージの関数定義には、 `autoload` の magic comment が付与されているので、
どうにかすれば、このパッケージの autoload するべき関数を、
autoload の対象として登録できると思っています。

質問:

- ローカルで git clone したパッケージの、`;;;###autoload` が付与された関数を、autoload の対象にするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-directory-autoloads` という関数が用意されているので、これで `*_autoloads.el` を生成します。仮に `docker.el` リポジトリを `/home/nemo/` に clone したとします。

```
(let ((generated-autoload-file "/home/nemo/docker.el/docker_autoloads.el"))
  (update-directory-autoloads "/home/nemo/docker.el"))
```

上記を実行するとリポジトリ内のファイルから `magic comment(";;;### autoloads")` を抽出して `docker_autoloads.el` に出力します。

**docker_autoloads.el**

```
;;; docker_autoloads.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:

;;;### (autoloads nil "docker" "docker.el" t)
;;; Generated autoloads from docker.el
                        :

(provide 'docker_autoloads)
                        :
```

もっとも、最終的にはこの `docker_autoloads.el` を load する必要はありますが。

```
(require 'docker_autoloads)
```